# IS NOT NULL in Cloudera-Impala

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, having-clause

I'm new on Impala, and I'm trying to write a query where one field is SUM(X), and I want to put a condition on that field.
When I used that query in MySQL, "HAVING SUM(X) IS NOT NULL" worked great - does anyone know what's the equivalent in Impala?

I tried a few ways, this is what I got:

- "HAVING SUM(X) IS NOT NULL" --> AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: isnull(STRING).
- "HAVING SUM(X) NOT NULL" --> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 93: HAVING SUM(X) NOT NULL ^ Encountered: NULL Expected: BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, REGEXP, RLIKE CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

If anyone has an answer for me I'd really appreciate it... Thank you!

Comment: please post and example of the query you are running

Answer (score -1):

Did you try *IF* conditional function?

```
HAVING IF(SUM(X) = NULL, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Documentation:
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_conditional_functions.html

Comment: You should never compare directly with = against NULL. This might always yield false regardless of what SUM(X) actually is.  For instance  select `IF( NULL = NULL, 1, 0 )`  yields  0 and not 1 as you would expect.  On the other hand `select IF( NULL != NULL,  1, 0 )` also yields 0 and not the negation of the former.... `select if( NULL is NULL, 1,  0 ), if( NULL is not NULL, 1, 0 )`  works as expected   I am talking about the specific case of Impala, here.   This is implementation independent, but the behaviour of Impala in this respect follows, the SQL standard, I believe.

Comment: By the way, in Impala,  a simple alternative to  `IF( expr,  false, true )`  is simply  `NOT( expr )`